# Different Bundle Product prices per store view?

Tags: magento-1.9, price, store-view, bundled-product

I'm attempting to set up **bundle products** with a **main fixed price** of 0 and prices and amounts specified in the "Bundle Items" section of product page. This is for promotions, so we can offer certain number of products or a set of products at reduced prices.

We have our prices set per store view, and it works fine for setting different prices of simple products. However, I can't seem to change the fixed prices of bundle items without it setting itself on every store view (including default). Does anyone have any tips/advice? To clarify, I set products and prices at the bottom of the left hand menu on the Bundle Product page titled "Bundle Items" and each is set to a fixed price of 0 in the "Prices" tab in this list.